# How to retrieve the count of total deals from the API PipeDrive

Tags: api, pipedrive-api

I am using the API PipeDrive official (see https://developers.pipedrive.com/v1). 
I want to retrieve the count of totals deals of a user, but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 4):

try to add *&get_summary=1* to the request

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - can confirm it works in the "additional_data" bit of the response